Why does TypeScript Type Inference Fail with Unimplemented Interface Method?
I have two TypeScript examples where I'm trying to ensure that a parameter type (Param) is inferred as string.
In the first example, it is inferred as string as expected. But in the second, it is inferred as unknown.
Here are the details:
Working Case
class Chat<T> {
    constructor(private adapter: BaseChatAdapter<T>) {}

    send(message: T) {}
}

interface BaseChatAdapter<T> {
    send(message: T): void;
}

class StringAdapter<T = string> implements BaseChatAdapter<T> {
    send(message: T) {}
}

const c = new Chat(new StringAdapter());

type Param = Parameters<typeof c['send']>[0]; // Param is inferred as string

Non-working Case
class Chat<T> {
    constructor(private adapter: BaseChatAdapter<T>) {}

    send(message: T) {}
}

interface BaseChatAdapter<T> {
    // The 'send' method is removed
}

class StringAdapter<T = string> implements BaseChatAdapter<T> {
    send(message: T) {}
}

const c = new Chat(new StringAdapter());

type Param = Parameters<typeof c['send']>[0]; // Param is inferred as unknown

In the second example, Param is inferred as unknown, even though I expect it to be string. The only difference between the two cases is the commented-out send method in the BaseChatAdapter interface.
Question:

Why does the absence of the send method in the BaseChatAdapter interface affect the type inference in the second example?

(Removed, see comments)


Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Please ask a single primary question here, not two related ones. Answer to question 1 is this FAQ entry. Answer to question 2 is "not really, make sure to actually use T structurally".  Does that fully address the question? If so, please [edit] to make one primary and I'll either write up an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

Thanks @jcalz I am mainly interested in 1. I agree with your answer in 2... for posterity here was the question you answered: 2. Is there a way to ensure Param is correctly inferred as string in the second case without explicitly defining the method in the interface?
